# Control Caps-Lock of android softkeypad

Tags: android

I have an `EditText`. The softkeypad should popup as "Caps on" state,  when I want to edit the editText. Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [InputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) property of the TextView class. Depending on what you exactly need, [TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS), [TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES) or [TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS) should do the job. You can set it either in the layout file or via code.

Comment: thank you very much for the response. I used android:capitalize="character" for overriding caps off to caps on softpad. I can also input small letters by pressing alt. In the same way is there any option to override default alphabet softpad to number softpad. But I also want to change from number to alphabet.

Comment: First be aware that the property Capitalize is deprecated. It's very likely that it will be removed in a future Android version. The SDK says you should use InputType instead. I think there is no way to set a standard softkeypad to number input mode while still being able to accept letters. If you know the first character is always a number, then you can initialize with InputType number and change it back to normal mode when the first character (a number) was entered. You listen for text changes with a TextWachter.