# Set num lock state on a hardware keyboard

Tags: android, android-keypad, android-input-method, android-event

Trying to set the num lock state to either always on or always off for an app. I'm guessing I can intercept the numlock press to keep the state, I'm just not sure how to set the initial state. Is there a way I can press the num lock key virtually?

Comment: I found this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953660/how-to-control-usb-hid-keyboards-caps-lock-from-android/35545074#35545074, but it doesn't go into a detailed answer.

Comment: I was hoping to use USBHost class to connect to the keyboard, but keyboards are handled by InputManager in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Been working on this a long time and it looks like the only option is to root your device.

I based my work on this article once I had rooted my device (a big thank you to Radu Motisan/pocketmagic);
http://www.pocketmagic.net/programmatically-injecting-events-on-android-part-2/

From there you can listen for num lock events and synthetically press the num lock key. I have this running on a separate thread. It works really well.